# Connecting a PC and Webserver without router

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, webserver, lan

I Have a Small Ubuntu Web Server setup on a device and know that it works as I use it to develop locally. I want to connect it to my laptop, withought using a router between it and my pc -> a single lan cable form the servers ethernet port to my Laptops Port.

After connecting, I ran ipconfig on my PCs Command Prompt and got this:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9da8:15c3:39d:b2e3%11
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.178.227
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Since there is no DCHP server in between, I am not getting a Default Gateway for me to connect to it.

Is it possible to do this without involving a router as the middle man, and if so, how?

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible - there are a number of ways to do this.   The easiest would be to assign a static IP address, netmask and gateway for each device (the server probably already has this).  There are plenty of [online tutorials](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/) on how to do this, but basically you find the network adaptor, select the IPv4 connection and add the values.

You would want the server and client to be in the same subnet - for example, 192.168.1.2 for the server and 192.168.1.3 for the client - with a netmask of 255.255.255.0 might be typical.  (You can leave the gateway blank, as well as the DNS).

You will want to add the domain name and IP address to the [hosts file](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hosts-file/) of the client found in 
    %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts  so that you can still access the server by domain name even in the absence of DNS.

I note that 169.254.x.x is not a valid IP address, its a temporary address you have until DHCP issues a real one.

On the Ubuntu (server I hope ?) side you would edit the file /etc/sysconfig/network/interfaces file and restart networking (eg by service networking restart) or use whatever GUI can do the same thing for you.

Comment: The temporary address you get via f.e. APIPA or AVAHI  is a valid class B Private address.

Comment: Maybe so, but how do you know which address has been assigned (being that APIPA randomly assigns the address), and what happens if a DHCP server presents itself ?

Comment: I do not disagree about the rest of your answer. 
You can connect to each other with 2 APIPA/AVAHI Addresses without setting up static ips. Its more convenient to use static addresses obviously.
Just your wording of "not a valid IP address" is wrong.
Additionally to specificy my own partly wrong command its not exactly a Private Adress but rather a link local Adress, described in RFC 3927.